# I have a bunch of csv files, I am reading them using pandas from python. I want to use a combination of map & lambda functions to do this

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, lambda, pandas

I have a bunch of csv files, I am reading them using pandas from python. I want to use a combination of map & lambda functions to do this.

I have tried this,

```
NN=pd.read_csv(filename[0].split('\n')[0])
map((lambda x: NN.append(pd.read_csv(x.split('\n')[0]))), filename)
```

the map function does not append to NN.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `concat` and a generator expression instead:

```
NN = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f.split('\n')[0]) for f in filename))
```

Comment: you should use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension